# How to create new planets and new sectors when modding Mindustry

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to put a new map onto the planet Serpulo, but when I do, it doesn't start waves.

The map code is this:

```
var map1 = SectorPreset('ventos-gelidos', Planets.serpulo, 145)
map1.localizedName = "Ventos Gélidosjkjjkjk"
map1.description = "Um lugar que, diferente de outros setores vanilla, contém a fruta Manga, com poucos inimigos."
map1.alwaysUnlocked = false
map1.difficulty = 4.5
map1.captureWave = 25
map1.startWaveTimeMultiplier = 3
map1.rules = Rules()
map1.rules.canGameOver = true
map1.rules.coreIncinerates = true
map1.rules.waves = true
map1.rules.waveSending = true
map1.rules.winWave = 25
map1.rules.dropZoneRadius = 25
```